# Remove last item from list

Tags: javascript

I'm trying the remove the last item from the list. The code I have completed removes the last item only but will not complete the rest.

I have tried but don't know what's going wrong

```js
function addList(entry) {
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var listNode = document.getElementById('list');
  var liNode = document.createElement("li");
  textNode = document.createTextNode(input);

  liNode.appendChild(textNode);
  listNode.appendChild(liNode);
}

function removeItem() {
  textNode.remove(input);
};
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>

<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="addList()">Add</button>
<button onclick="removeItem()">Remove item</button>
```

Comment: You could always just do `textNode.removeChild(textNode.lastChild)` if you're always looking to delete the last node.

Answer (score 0):

As you ask "last item in your list" so get the list and search for the last item and remove it...

```
function removeItem() {
    let list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.removeChild(list.lastChild)
};
```

Comment: Great, Thank you very much. Self-learning is a bummer but a blessing I wouldn't trade for any other way.... Helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can remove elements from their parent in multiple ways.

```js
function addItemFirst() {
  let listNode = document.getElementById('list');
  let currentText = document.getElementById('input').value.trim();
  let liNode = document.createElement('li');
  liNode.textContent = currentText;
  listNode.insertBefore(liNode, listNode.firstElementChild);
}

function addItemLast() {
  let listNode = document.getElementById('list');
  let currentText = document.getElementById('input').value.trim();
  let liNode = document.createElement('li');
  liNode.textContent = currentText;
  listNode.appendChild(liNode);
}

function removeOneBy() {
  let currentText = document.getElementById('input').value.trim();
  let listNode = document.getElementById('list');
  let children = listNode.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (children[i] && children[i].textContent === currentText) {
      listNode.removeChild(children[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
};

function removeAllBy() {
  let currentText = document.getElementById('input').value.trim();
  let listNode = document.getElementById('list');
  let children = listNode.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (children[i] && children[i].textContent === currentText) {
      listNode.removeChild(children[i]);
    }
  }
};

function removeFirstItem() {
  let listNode = document.getElementById('list');
  var firstChild = listNode.firstElementChild;  
  if (firstChild) {
    listNode.removeChild(firstChild); 
  } 
};

function removeLastItem() {
  let listNode = document.getElementById('list');
  var lastChild = listNode.lastElementChild;  
  if (lastChild) {
    listNode.removeChild(lastChild); 
  } 
};

function removeAll() {
  let listNode = document.getElementById('list');
  var child = listNode.lastElementChild;  
  while (child) { 
    listNode.removeChild(child); 
    child = listNode.lastElementChild; 
  } 
};
```

```css
#list {
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="addItemFirst()">Add First</button>
<button onclick="addItemLast()">Add Last</button>
<br />
<button onclick="removeOneBy()">Remove One (current text)</button>
<button onclick="removeAllBy()">Remove All (current text)</button>
<br />
<button onclick="removeFirstItem()">Remove First</button>
<button onclick="removeLastItem()">Remove Last</button>
<button onclick="removeAll()">Remove All</button>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Very helpful, you went far and beyond my expectations of a simple answer. Much appreciated.